# compare 2 files, find a string, and report several lines from one of them

Tags: perl, awk

I would like to compare and report the similar string in 2 files:
each time, read 1 line of file1, search in file2 for the string, if could find it in file2, print one line before, string and 2 line after the string

infile2:

```
john
jack
jeff
```

infile1:

```
22894
john
street3
city
56438
danny
street2
city
22894
john
street3
city
33456
jeff
street2
city
22894
john
street3
city
```

output

```
22894
john
street3
city
22894
john
street3
city
33456
jeff
street2
city
22894
john
street3
city
```

I could write a perl script for that
perl script.pl infile2 infile1

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;


my ($infile1) = $ARGV[0];
my ($infile2) = $ARGV[1];
open(my $fh1, "<$infile1");
open(my $fh2, "<$infile2");

while(( my @lines = map ~~<$fh1>, 1 .. 4 )[0] and (my $names = <$fh2>)) {
    #print $lines[1];
    #print "\n";        


        if ($lines[1] eq $names){
                print ("$lines[0]$lines[1]$lines[2]$lines[3]");}
                }
print ("\n");
```

but I get only

```
22894
john
street3
city
```

Comment: Some things are missing: sample input, sample output and [more important] your attempts.

Comment: This is definitely __too broad__.

Comment: Sounds like [`grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) to me. `grep -f file1 -B1 -A2 file2` perhaps?

Comment: @TLP I think your comment is a perfect solution for this - you could post as an answer. I would add `-w` to grep just to make sure it matches a whole word.

Comment: @fedorqui Well, I was not sure it was what he wanted, or if it worked. But worth a hint in the form of a comment, perhaps.

Comment: @TLP Could you please help me with the perl code

Comment: Why not just get a list of names, parse through the data file and print each record as it comes?

Comment: Your requirements appear to be incomplete. For example, should the match be case-sensitive or not? More importantly, describe what you'd want to happen if "john" was in infile2 and someone named bob lived on "john st." or in a town named "john" in infile1. As always with these sorts of problems, it's very easy to come up with various solutions to find the patterns you want, but it's much harder to come up with solutions that exclude the patterns you don't want. Think about possible edge cases and then update your sample input and expected output to show the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Input files

```
 root@Aix:/tmp# cat file2
 john
 jack
 jeff

 root@Aix:/tmp# cat file1
 22894
 john
 street3
 city
 56438
 danny
 street2
 city
 22894
 john
 street3
 city
 33456
 jeff
 street2
 city
 22894
 john
 street3
 city
```

## Awk Code

```
 root@Aix:/tmp# cat test.sh

 awk '     FNR==NR{
                   A[$1]             # Array 'A' holds key to search 
                   next
                  }
 # if previous and column1 of file1 in found in Array 'A' of file2 
 (p && ($1 in A)){

                   # counter reset after search found
                   i=0 

                   # We found that key we found, so print previous line and current line            
                   print p RS $0     

                   # Number of lines to print after key found
                   while(++i<=number_of_lines)
                                {     
                                 getline
                                 print
                                }
                }

                {
                  # Previous line is assigned to variable p
                  p=$0
                }
    ' number_of_lines="2" file2 file1
```

Resulting

```
 # sh test.sh
 22894
 john
 street3
 city
 22894
 john
 street3
 city
 33456
 jeff
 street2
 city
 22894
 john
 street3
 city
```

If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS system`, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`

Change `number_of_lines="2"` according to your need.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I think you really need at a minimum to avoid false matches in other parts of your file of address records:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {names[$0]; next }
{
    lineNr = ((FNR+3)%4)+1
    rec = rec $0 ORS
}
lineNr == 2 { name = $0 }
lineNr == 4 {
    if (name in names) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec=""
}
' file2 file1
22894
john
street3
city
22894
john
street3
city
33456
jeff
street2
city
22894
john
street3
city
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $file2, $last ) = pop;
my %hash = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <>;

push @ARGV, $file2;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print "$last\n$_\n" . <> . <> if $hash{$_};
    $last = $_;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile2 inFile1 [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

The inFiles are named after your usage; the smaller file of proper names comes first.

This first `pop`s off and saves the second file name for later, then creates a hash of the proper names.  It then iterates through the second file, printing the last and next two lines if the current line is in the proper names' file.  The variable `$last` isn't immediately initialized, since a match will not occur until there is a prior line.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk solution:

```
awk -f a.awk file2 file1
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
NR==FNR {
    a[$1]++
    next
}
{
    b[FNR]=$0
}

END {
    for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++)
        if (b[i] in a) 
            for (j=i-1; j<=i+2; j++)
                print b[j]
}
```

Output:

```
22894
john
street3
city
22894
john
street3
city
33456
jeff
street2
city
22894
john
street3
city
```

Comment: Change the first END loop to `for (i=2; i<FNR; i+=4)` to only match on the name field, which I think is what's really desired, otherwise if someone lives in a town named `john` you'll get a partial print of the preceding and succeeding records.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah.. That's probably whats needed.. But I prefer being lazy.. Leave some surprises to the OP also :)

Comment: Got it. It's kinda like unwrapping a Christmas present but you get to do it every time you run the script on new input :-).